# HTML Select Option Validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

How would I alert out that the selection must not be be blank in plain JavaScript?

Here is my code for my option menu:

```
<div class="interest">
    <label for="interest">Interest Area *</label>
    
    <select name="interest">
    <option value="blank"></option>
    <option value="option1"> EXAMPLE 2 </option>
    <option value="option2"> EXAMPLE 3 </option>
    <option value="option3"> EXAMPLE 4 </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByName('interest')[0].onchange = function() {
     if (this.value=='blank') alert('Select something !');
}
```

or in a submit handler or similar, just check the value

```
if ( document.getElementsByName('interest')[0].value == 'blank' )
    alert('Select something !');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use '.selectedIndex' to return the index of selected value and check if its equal to blank( 0 in your case) or not

```
if(0 == document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].selectedIndex){
alert("Please select a value first")
return;
}
```

You can also use Jquery for selection instead of document.getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0):

I feel the easiest way to do it is with html using required on the select all the best

Interest Area *

```
        <select required name="interest">
        <option value="blank"></option>
        <option value="option1"> EXAMPLE 2 </option>
        <option value="option2"> EXAMPLE 3 </option>
        <option value="option3"> EXAMPLE 4 </option>
        </select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In general, check if the selectElement.value is "blank" in a simple if statement.